# Can I have an organized way to work with django?

Tags: django, angular

I come from an Mean, Express, Angular and Node (MEAN) stack background. I really liked how angular has separate components and then we can style each components and then nest them in each other. It is just more organized and way more shareable when in companies. It gets easier to actually understand the structure. Can I do this in django since I notice that my css is supposed to be all in one static file. Is it possible?

NOTE: Angular not Angular.js

Comment: The css does *not* have to be all in one static file... You can write as many static files as you want. In fact you can use angular as a frontend, and let Django do the backend work.

Comment: How? Any Sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [webpack](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-tutorial/) method. Could not find this tutorial easily on googling.

Answer (score 1):

While all your static files do need to be contained in one folder in production, they can be in separate places in development.

**Development: Separated**

You can have separate static files for each app within the project, but each should contain a folder with the name of the app. So the path to the static file `style.css` in the app `myapp` would look like: `myproject/myapp/static/myapp/style.css`. You can also put more folders within the `myproject/myapp/static/myapp` to separate images, JS, and CSS, for example.

To have this work you need to make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then make some edits in `settings.py` and set `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and `STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]`, so that Django knows the URL to refer to as well as the folders to check for static files.

**Production: Collected**

The above will only work if `DEBUG` is set to `True`, so it will only work in development. To have it work in production, you need to set `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`, so that Django will know to look in `myproject/staticfiles` to find static files.

Then just run `python manage.py collectstatic` and Django will go through all your apps and pull everything from the folders called `static` within them and place everything in `STATIC_ROOT`.

This is why it's helpful to use the convention of putting a folder called `myapp` within `static` in `myapp`—because they all end up in the same folder.

See the docs for more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/